# Allow sbt.ivy to download artifacts using https repository with self-signed certificate

Tags: maven, playframework, ssl-certificate, playframework-2.1

I have the next error accessing to https repository using self-signed certificate.

> [error] Server access Error:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider .certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>   url=https://example.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/microsoft/sqlserver/4.0.jdbc4/sqlserver-4.0.jdbc4.pom

I have added the server certificate using `keytool`, but it continue not working.

On the other hand, using the same JVM version (jdk_7.0.15) maven works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have several jdk and jre in my system. the problem was using different versions. using keytool with correct version solved the problem